# Can someone confirm if my answer is correct? (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

> Question: Drug testing authorities arrive at a cycling race to test 20% of the riders. There are 25 riders, and those to be tested are selected randomly. How many possible combination of riders are there who are to be tested ?

My logic:

- To be tested will be 0.2(25)=5 riders.
- combination of riders: 5! = 120 combinations

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

EDIT:

- Okay so my second bullet is wrong.
- Answer should be 25C5

> Second part of question: Now authorities decide they should test winner, runner up and then remaining 20% of riders randomly. In the race with 25 riders, how many possible combinations of riders will be tested?

Having learnt my mistake from part a) so it should be :

- 25C1 to select the winner
- 24C1 to select the runner up
- 23C3 to select the remaining 3 riders
- so Ans: 25*24*23C3

Am I correct? Thank you.

- But wait there can only be one winner and one runner up, so it should be 23C3 only?

Comment: you are looking at permutations of 5 riders rather than combination of 5 riders. To make sense consider this example: There are 3 balls yellow(Y),red (R),blue(B) in how many ways we can select two balls?  We may select (R,Y) or (R,B) or (B,Y) so there are 3 ways. But according to what you did it should be 3!=6 which is clearly wrong

Comment: Oh so it is 25C5? @Mathematical Curiosity

Comment: Yes(late reply)

Comment: @Mathematical Curiosity can you help me check for the 2nd part too?

Comment: Is the question correct? 20 ℅ of remaining riders(23) is not a whole number??

Answer (score 1):

Your first bullet is correct but the second isn't.

**Hint:**

You actually want to *choose* $5$ riders out of $25$. How can you do that?

Comment: Can you please check my 2nd part ?

Comment: @Isabel There's a bit of a problem: what does "remaining 20% of riders" mean? Because 20% of 23 people is 4.6 people and *that's* a problem. Also, it could also be possible that the winner, the runner up and the 3 people from the remaining *together* form the 20%. In this case, your initial attempt is correct.